# Derby slows down after 1.2 million records

Tags: mysql, insert, java, derby

I'm using a Derby database, mass insertions slow down to 1/4 to 1/6 the speed once there are 1.2 million records (about 6 GB database size, one major table, other tables are tiny). Is that normal?  Is there something I can do to tweak it and make it run faster?  I compressed the main table.

## Questions

- Should I consider other databases?
- How could I compare Derby's performance, with, say, MySQL in this kind of scenario?
- Are there such comparisons already?

(Running on Windows 7-based server R2, 16GB RAM, 8-core machine).

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER : Not a Derby Expert

## DERBY

There are options you can set to [increase data pages for Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/tuning/rtunproper81359.html)

For a mass load of table `prodtable`, you may want to consider

- create temptable just like prodtable, but with no indexes
- load data into the temptable
- rebuild indexes on temptable
- rename prodtable to zaptable
- rename temptable to prodtable
- drop zaptable

## MySQL

If you switch over to MySQL, you could do wonderful things to performance tune data processing

- Start with using only InnoDB
- You can configure InnoDB to

  - hyperthread read threads
  - hyperthread write threads
  - access multiple CPUs/Cores
  - setup partitions buffer pools

Here are some of my past posts on configuring InnoDB in MySQL for multicore performance

- [Is the CPU performance relevant for a database server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17092/is-the-cpu-performance-relevant-for-a-database-server/17098#17098) (Apr 26, 2012)
- [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968) (Sep 20, 2011)
- [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670) (Sep 12, 2011)
- [How do you tune MySQL for a heavy InnoDB workload?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload/1185#1185) (Feb 12, 2011)

While I may be a little biased towards MySQL, [**make sure you have Derby's caching configured to accommodate mass INSERTs**](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/tuning/tuningderby.pdf). That way, you need not perform a major data migration if Derby can be made to handle large transactions.

Comment: I will experiment with page size and server memory and report back (may take some time).  Also, Derby documentation suggests multiple writes in one transaction (turn off autocommit, write a bunch of records, then commit).

Comment: do you know of any performance comparisons for MySQL with other databases?

Comment: See the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems