# mysqldump 5.5.25 use swap instead of memory

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

mysql version 5.5.25, while use mysqldump to dump big tables, it eat lots of swap while there is lots of free memory.

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32177      31427        749          0        208      10747
-/+ buffers/cache:      20471      11705
Swap:        16002      12952       3049

# cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness 
5

#[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

Comment: I don't see "lots" of free memory. 31427 / 32177 = 97.6% used memory, 749 / 32177 = 2.4% free memory.

Comment: There is 10GB free, the problem is that mysqldump bloats the pagecache. It’s a pitty Linux still has that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that `mysqldump` normally caches the results it produces.
You have to use the `--quick` option, to prevent this.

```
 --quick, -q
```

*This option is useful for dumping large tables. It forces `mysqldump` to retrieve rows for a table from the server a row at a time rather than retrieving the entire row set and buffering it in memory before writing it out.*

Comment: there is quick option in mysql config file:
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

Comment: i dont understand you comment ? was my answer correct ! it improved the speed of your mysqldump ?

Comment: i have using the --quick option already. but the same.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, you can only do but so much. I would recommend upgrading to 5.7

## SUGGESTION 1 : Increase Buffer Pool Instances

To address some swapping issues in the past, I have set innodb_buffer_pool_instances to the number of CPUs. (See my answer to  [How do you tune MySQL for a heavy InnoDB workload?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload/1185#1185))

If you upgrade to MySQL 5.7, the default is 8. This will lower the incidence of swapping.

## SUGGESTION #2 : Dump the Buffer Pool to Disk

Dump the Buffer Pool before the mysqldump

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now = 1;
```

Execute the mysqldump, then run

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_load_now = 1;
```

Now the Buffer Pool is has the same Data and Index Pages it had before the dump

This is only possible in MySQL 5.6/5.7