# Optimal Number of MySQL InnoDB Buffer Pool Instances

Tags: mysql, innodb, buffer-pool

## Server Characteristics

- Total system RAM: 8GB (running MySQL + other stuff than MySQL on it i.e. not dedicated to MySQL)
- Number of CPU Cores: 6
- I have data in the db amounting to about 2GB
- I have InnoDB Buffer Pool Size set to 4GB

Which is better:

- Innodb Buffer Pool Instances set to 1?
- Innodb Buffer Pool Instances set to 2 (2GB in each)?
- Innodb Buffer Pool Instances set to 4 (1GB in each)?
- Innodb Buffer Pool Instances set to 8 (the default setting)

I'm thus not sure as to how to reason when it comes to Buffer Pool Instances and also the whole "use instances or suffer OS Swap when having such large InnoDB Buffer Pool Size".

Comment: Where did you get "use instances or suffer OS Swap when having such large InnoDB Buffer Pool Size"?

Comment: 70% of RAM for the total buffer_pool _after_ subtracting off space for "other stuff than MySQL" should be fine, regardless of the number of instances.

Comment: I cannot set any answers to accepted so far as I deem them all to be "shoot from the hip". If anyone wonders, I went with 4G buffer pool size and 2 instances and it works very well on Debian 8.1 with 8G of total memory running php-fpm + nginx on the same machine with approx  mysql running at an average of 60 queries / second.

Answer (score 10):

When I go back to MySQL 5.5, I would think about this same thing.

What I learned over those years was the following: If the Buffer Pool was bigger than half the installed RAM and [**innodb_buffer_pool_instances**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) was 1 (default for 5.5), the threat of swapping was always imminent.

I discussed this before : [Is there a rule of thumb regarding the size and number of a buffer pool instances?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-regarding-the-size-and-number-of-a-buffer-pool-instance/62480#62480). In that post, I mentioned an example of a client who had 192GB RAM on the server with 162GB Buffer Pool. When [**innodb_buffer_pool_instances**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) was 1, swapping happened. When I set [**innodb_buffer_pool_instances**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) to 2, things got way better.

In your case, since the Buffer Pool is exactly half, a value of 1 may be OK. I would not chance it. I would set it to 2.

Since MySQL 5.6 has a default of 8, you shouldn't have to think about it anymore.

I will say this: [akuzminsky's answer has the highest principle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115141/877). My answer is just shooting from hip based on past experiences (good and bad).

Comment: No way!  Swapping is dependent on amount of memory allocated, not on pool instances.

Comment: Good to know the default is 8... But what's the difference if it was cut to 4 or increased to 16? Is there any memory/storage penalty or benefit? The only reason I'm here really, mysqltuner recommends innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=1) but I don't always trust its recommendations. Granted, I'm not having problems, just curious.

Comment: @PJBrunet  if the InnoDB buffer pool is less than half of RAM, then the  InnoDB buffer pool instances can be left at 1.

Answer (score 7):

Number of buffer pool instances should be increased to avoid buffer pool mutex contention.

With buffer pool size 8GB I doubt you'll ever see the buffer pool mutex contention.

**UPDATE 0**:

I mention 8Gb buffer pool in the answer while in the original question the total memory was 8GB. Sure, the buffer pool must be less than 8GB. 4GB sounds like a good start but make sure no swapping happens.

**UPDATE 1**:

// from [Yasufumi's slides](https://www.percona.com/resources/technical-presentations/how-fulfill-potential-innodb-performance-and-scalability-mysql-uc) (in recent MySQL versions output may slightly differ)

To determine if there is a contention on the buffer pool mutex collect a dozen of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` samples during the peak time.

Then aggregate it using shell snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat $1.innodb | grep "Mutex at " | cut -d"," -f1 | sort | uniq -c > /tmp/tmp1.txt 
cat $1.innodb | grep "lock on " | cut -d"-"
-f2- | sort | uniq -c > /tmp/tmp2.txt
cat /tmp/tmp1.txt /tmp/tmp2.txt | sort -n > $1.contention rm /tmp/tmp1.txt /tmp/tmp2.txt
```

which gives output like this:

```
.....
4 lock on RW-latch at 0x7fb86b2c9138 created in file dict/dict0dict.c line 1356
6 lock on RW-latch at 0x7fb86b2c4138 created in file dict/dict0dict.c line 1356
12 lock on RW-latch at 0x7fb86b2d9538 created in file dict/dict0dict.c line 1356
20 lock on RW-latch at 0x7fb86b2db138 created in file dict/dict0dict.c line 1356
22 Mutex at 0x7fb86b28f0e0 created file btr/btr0sea.c line 139
30 lock on RW-latch at 0x7fb86b2ba938 created in file dict/dict0dict.c line 1356
36 lock on RW-latch at 0x7fb86b2bad38 created in file dict/dict0dict.c line 1356
71 Mutex at 0x7fb86b28ecb8 created file buf/buf0buf.c line 597
164 lock on RW-latch at 0x7fb86b28f0b8 created in file btr/btr0sea.c line 139
```

If you see high count of buffer pool mutex waits, then it's time to consider multiple buffer pool instances. The contention is unlikely to happen on a buffer pool smaller than ~48G.

Comment: But do _not_ have a 8G buffer_pool in only 8GB of RAM !

Comment: At what dbsize i.e. innodb buffer pool size _would_ you start thinking about  instances then? I interpret your answer to be that at these relatively _small_ levels, there's no reason to have more than one. Correct? You got a source on this being so? The MySQL documentation says "multi gigabyte" which - to me - is a very fuzzy way of expressing things. In fact, 2 GB is multi but I _think_ they refer to a larger dataset than that...

Answer (score 2):

Set "swappiness" to 1 if your OS has such.  The problem may be an overly aggressive OOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting this to match the maximum number of MySQL threads that you want to run simultaneously.  I use the number of cores.

I also set `innodb_read_io_threads` and `innodb_write_io_threads` to match this number.

If `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is too low, your threads are likely to get stuck in semaphore waits.  This makes both the CPU and I/O appear to be idle, even though the system should be busy -- and your application latency will go through the roof.